# Parallel REST API request using Spark(Databricks)

Tags: rest, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to leverage Spark(It is running on Databricks and I am using PySpark) in order to send parallel requests towards a REST API. Right now I might face two scenarios:

- REST API 1: Returns data of the order of ~MB
- REST API 2: Returns data of the order of ~KB.

Any suggestions on how to distribute requests among nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Just create a dataframe with URLs (if you use different ones) and arguments for the API (if they aren't part of URL) - this could be done either via [creating it explicitly](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark/) from list, etc. or by reading data from external data source, like JSON files or something like (the `spark.read` function).

And then you define the [user defined function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/) that will perform requests to the REST API and return data as a column. Something like this (not tested):

```py
import urllib
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [("url1", "params1"), ("url2", "params2")],
  ("url", "params"))

@udf("body string, status int")
def do_request(url: str, params: str):
  with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    status = f.status
    body = f.read().decode("utf-8")
  
  return {'status': status, 'body': body}
  

res = df.withColumn("result", do_requests(col("url"), col("params")))
```

This will return dataframe with new column called `result` that will have two fields - `status` and `body` (JSON answer).  You need to add error handling, etc.

Comment: Any suggestions on how can we. execute a REST API call through java using spark?

Comment: similarly, or do `.rdd.mapPartitions`, ...

Comment: @AlexOtt I am facing a similar issue. Is this the most performant way? Or is it in this case possible to use a pandas_udf?

Comment: You can use Pandas UDF for that, but you may need to decrease the batch size if your results are big

Comment: @AlexOtt, I have been trying this out, but wasn't able to make this work yet. Is getting the content of an URL using the requests library something that would benefit from a pandas_udf compared to a Python udf, or not really?

Comment: It will benefit if you make requests to the same site and do connection reuse