# Send payload to API row by row and write it in table in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying in pyspark to send a payload to an API and row by row and write it in a delta table in the manner (each row after getting the response). The code looks like below:

```
%python
import requests
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Define a function to send the payload to the API and extract the response
def send_payload(row):
    payload = row['Payload']
    item_key_name = row['ItemKeyName']
    item_key_value = row['ItemKeyValue']

    api_url = "https://test/API/test/test"

    # Define the headers
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/data"
    }
    print("Sending request...")

    # Make the API request
    response = requests.post(api_url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)

   # Insert the response data into a temporary table
    spark.sql(f"""
        INSERT INTO TABLE temp_response_table
        SELECT
            NULL AS Id,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS DataFlowDateTime,
            CAST(date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyyMMdd') AS INT) AS DataFlowDate,
            '{item_key_name}' AS ItemKeyType,
            '{item_key_value}' AS ItemKeyValue,
            '{payload}' AS Payload,
            {response.status_code} AS ResponseStatus,
            '{response.text}' AS Response
    """)

    # Return the response data as a Row
    return Row(ItemKeyName=item_key_name, ItemKeyValue=item_key_value, Payload=payload,ResponseStatus = response.status_code , Response=response.json())

# Apply the function to each row using foreach and collect the results
response_data = df.rdd.map(lambda row: send_payload(row)).collect()

# Create a DataFrame from the response data
response_df = spark.createDataFrame(response_data)

response_df.createOrReplaceTempView("response_view")

# Print the DataFrame
response_df.display()
```

The error I am facing is this:

> RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference
> SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation.
> SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run
> on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063. PicklingError: Could
> not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting
> to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or
> transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in
> code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Any idea how I can manage to do that?

Comment: Just use UDF for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204599/parallel-rest-api-request-using-sparkdatabricks/67208855#67208855

Comment: @AlexOtt How come this above answer satisfy above issue, answer you mentioned is about parallel API request, but OP need mysql insertion, after the request. As per the question API request status needed to be uploaded into  mysql table, row by row

Comment: No MySQL is mentioned in the question - it’s about storing data in delta table

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to use SparkContext/SparkSession inside a map, Which you're currently using when you're inserting Response into delta table.

To avoid this issue, instead of using `spark.sql` to insert the response, use python mysql connection packages.

To do so, you can use any mysql packages. Please find below example
Using `mysql-connector-python` `pip` package

```
import mysql.connector

def def send_payload(row):
    
    # You're API CALL

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="****",
        database="application"
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO  delta(num1, num2) VALUES({row[1]}, {row[2]})")
    mydb.commit()
    mycursor.close()
    mydb.close()

    return Row(....)


response_data = df.rdd.map(lambda row: send_payload(row)).collect()
```

Issue with above code is that, Creating connection object has time and resource overhead. Therefor Creating and Destroying connection object for each record will reduce the throughput.

#### Why can't we create mydb object outside the function and pass it in the map..?

```
response_data = df.rdd.map(lambda row: send_payload(row, mydb)).collect()
```

This will cause serialisation issue (since db object cannot be pickled)

So one preferred approach to this solution is to use `mapPartitions` instead `map`

```
import mysql.connector

def def send_payload(partition):

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="***",
        database="application"
    )
    
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    
    for row in partition:

        # You're API call

        mycursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO  delta(num1, num2) VALUES({row[1]}, {row[2]})")
        mydb.commit()

        yield Row(....)

    mycursor.close()
    mydb.close()



response_data = df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda partition: send_payload(partition)).collect()
```

This will reduce the connection objects creation significantly.

Prev `conn_obj == number of record`

Now `conn_obj == number of partition`

Make sure that , you're not having small size problem (High number of partitions for small amount data)