# How to fix data loss in multi threading with API calls and appending data to a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have an API call: `<API_URL>` that will return a payload. Each API call corresponds to 1 record which should be ingested into a table.

There are 200,000 records that I need to ingest in my table, so I ran them in a loop by ingesting one by one and it took almost 5hours. I checked the logs and it was taking time to do all the file system updates, snapshots, log updates. For every insert, this process is repeated i.e., 200,000 times hence it is taking so long to complete processing small amount of records.

So I created an empty DataFrame and then kept appending each api call's output to it so that I have one single dataframe where I accumulate all the data and then simply write it into a table.
This is how I implemented multi threading in Python.

```
def prepare_empty_df(schema, spark: SparkSession) -> DataFrame:
    empty_rdd = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
    empty_df = spark.createDataFrame(empty_rdd, schema)
    return empty_df

class RunApiCalls:
    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame=None):
        self.finalDf = df


    def do_some_transformations(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
        return do_some_transformation_output_dataframe


    def get_json(self, spark, PARAMETER):
        try:
            token_headers = create_bearer_token()
            session = get_session()
            api_response = session.get(f'API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER}', headers=token_headers)
            print(f'API call: API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER} -> Status code: {api_response.status_code}')
            api_json_object = json.loads(api_response.text)
            string_data = json.dumps(api_json_object)
            json_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, string_data)],["id","value"])
            api_dataframe = do_some_transformations(json_df)
            self.finalDf = self.finalDf.unionAll(api_dataframe)
        except Exception as error:  
            traceback.print_exc()

    def api_main(self, spark, batch_size, state_names) -> DataFrame:
        try:
            for i in range(0, len(state_names), batch_size):
                sub_list = state_names[i:i + batch_size]
                threads = []
                for index in range(len(sub_list)):
                    t = threading.Thread(target=self.get_json, name=str(index), args=(spark, sub_list[index]))
                    threads.append(t)
                    t.start()
                for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
                    thread.join()
                print(f"All Threads completed for this sub_list{i}")
            return self.finalDf
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SOME_APP_NAME').getOrCreate()
    batch_size = 15
    empty_df = prepare_empty_df(schema=schema, spark=spark)
    print('Created Empty Dataframe')
    api_param_list = get_list()
    print(f'api param list: {api_param_list}')
    api_call = RunApiCalls(df=empty_df)
    final_df = api_call.api_main(spark=spark, batch_size=batch_size, state_names=api_param_list)
    final_df.write.mode('append').saveAsTable("some_database.some_tablebname")
```

When I submit this code, I could see multi threads running in the background and their log as well.
Log:

```
All Threads completed for this sub_list0
API call: API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER} -> Status code: 200
....
API call: API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER} -> Status code: 200
All Threads completed for this sub_list15
API call: API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER} -> Status code: 200
....
API call: API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER} -> Status code: 200
All Threads completed for this sub_list30
API call: API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER} -> Status code: 200
..
..
..
API call: API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER} -> Status code: 200
All Threads completed for this sub_list199985
```

[image]

In `do_some_transformations()`, I am doing nothing but applying a schema to the json output.
There are no errors/failures while I dump data into the table as well.
But when I checked the table for data, I don't see all of the records.
`select count(*) from some_database.some_tablebname` I only see `1735` records (result shown in the screenshot).
Also this count varies every time I run all of the threads. Sometimes it becomes `5000`, sometimes its is `8000` and henceforth.

All the API calls have status code of `200` and I also printed the content of API responses once and saw that the API calls are indeed returning data.
Could anyone let me know if I am doing any mistake here so that I can see the entire amount of data i.e. as many number of rows as they are in my list.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating shared resources in the threads which can be interrupted, loosing data. Consider

```
self.finalDf = self.finalDf.unionAll(api_dataframe)
```

suppose a different thread makes the same call while the right side of this one is running. It will assign old stale data to `self.finalDf` when it finally completes. Instead, you could add a lock to protect the dataframe in this step. In the following example, I added `finalDfLock`.

```
import threading

def prepare_empty_df(schema, spark: SparkSession) -> DataFrame:
    empty_rdd = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
    empty_df = spark.createDataFrame(empty_rdd, schema)
    return empty_df

class RunApiCalls:
    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame=None):
        self.finalDf = df
        self.finalDfLock = threading.RLock()

    def do_some_transformations(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
        return do_some_transformation_output_dataframe


    def get_json(self, spark, PARAMETER):
        try:
            token_headers = create_bearer_token()
            session = get_session()
            api_response = session.get(f'API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER}', headers=token_headers)
            print(f'API call: API_URL/?API_PARAMETER={PARAMETER} -> Status code: {api_response.status_code}')
            api_json_object = json.loads(api_response.text)
            string_data = json.dumps(api_json_object)
            json_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, string_data)],["id","value"])
            api_dataframe = do_some_transformations(json_df)
            with self.finalDfLock:
                self.finalDf = self.finalDf.unionAll(api_dataframe)
        except Exception as error:  
            traceback.print_exc()

    def api_main(self, spark, batch_size, state_names) -> DataFrame:
        try:
            for i in range(0, len(state_names), batch_size):
                sub_list = state_names[i:i + batch_size]
                threads = []
                for index in range(len(sub_list)):
                    t = threading.Thread(target=self.get_json, name=str(index), args=(spark, sub_list[index]))
                    threads.append(t)
                    t.start()
                for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
                    thread.join()
                print(f"All Threads completed for this sub_list{i}")
            return self.finalDf
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SOME_APP_NAME').getOrCreate()
    batch_size = 15
    empty_df = prepare_empty_df(schema=schema, spark=spark)
    print('Created Empty Dataframe')
    api_param_list = get_list()
    print(f'api param list: {api_param_list}')
    api_call = RunApiCalls(df=empty_df)
    final_df = api_call.api_main(spark=spark, batch_size=batch_size, state_names=api_param_list)
    final_df.write.mode('append').saveAsTable("some_database.some_tablebname")
```

Comment: I was checking the lock options earlier and saw this: `threading.Lock()` Can you please let me know how is `RLock()` different from `Lock()`? Would it increase performance in anyway?

Comment: `RLock` is a re-entrant lock, meaning that a single thread acquiring twice will succeed. With `Lock`, a thread trying to get a lock it has already  acquired will hang forever. They have about the same performance, especially in this context. In C, and for a lock acquired extremely often, or where you need very low latency, the performance difference may matter. But its lost in the wash for a python program.

Comment: `Rlock` may hide bugs, though. You could have the same problem where two bits of your code are updating the variable in the wrong order, one overwriting the other.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you're running everything on the driver node and not taking advantage of Spark's code parallelization. It's better to implement your code as a user-defined function, generate a dataframe with URLs & parameters, and run the code in parallel (given that the REST API is able to handle the load). The code for implementing UDF could be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204599/parallel-rest-api-request-using-sparkdatabricks/67208855#67208855).